# How to execute SQL query inside a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to execute this function:

```
<?php
function registerDevice(){

        $query = "INSERT INTO devices (device,username) VALUES (:device,:username)";

         $query_params = array(
        ':device' => $_POST['device'],
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
    );


        try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["result"] = "Error154";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }



    }
registerDevice();
?>
```

The method is works successfully if is not called when is outside the function:

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO devices (device,username) VALUES (:device,:username)";

             $query_params = array(
            ':device' => $_POST['device'],
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        );


            try {
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["result"] = "Error154";
            die(json_encode($response));

        }
?>
```

but when i call the function the function does not work at all. I hope you guys can help me out. Thanks

Comment: i can see an extra } there at the end of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is `$db` variable. You never show how it's initialized: I assume it's created by some external (`require`) file responsible for creating a connection to DB and storing it into `$db` var. As file boundaries do not create separate scopes in PHP, that variable is left in the global scope.

It's not a good practice, but it works when the code using `$db` is also placed in the global scope. But it breaks when the code is moved into a function, which introduces a new - isolated - scope.

(*I'd suggest checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and) and its answers, it explains a lot about intricacies of PHP; and believe me, there are some*)

One possible way out of this mess is explicitly passing the value of `$db` variable into `registerDevice` function as its param. This obviously requires changes in the signature:

```
function registerDevice($db) {
  // ... the rest of the code is the same    
}
registerDevice($db);
```

Note that `$_POST` variable is a different beast. Actually, there's more of them - `$_GET`, `$_SERVER` and so on, those wild things also known as PHP [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). You can safely (sort of) use them within any part of your code, whenever it introduces a new scope or not. That's why they're called superglobals, after all.

Still, even with all the power in your disposal it might be a great idea adjusting your function so that it doesn't depend on any magic:

```
function registerDevice($db, $deviceId, $username) {
  // ... the code is the same    
}

if (isset($_POST['device'], $_POST['username'])) {
  registerDevice($db, $_POST['device'], $_POST['username']);
}
else {
  // something is not right with the request
}
```

The change might seem insignificant, but now your function can take inputs from *any* source, becoming a step closer to a truly autonomous entity. That, among other things, allows you to 1) test this function in an isolation; 2) reuse this function in other parts of your application.

Comment: Yeap. that is definitely the right answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Again I'd suggest checking the docs and the linked SO material, it explains a LOT. )